# Convert AxesImage Histogram to Arrays Histogram

Tags: python, opencv, histogram, hsv

### Hi everyone my code below here.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import PIL
from matplotlib import pyplot

img1 = cv2.imread('D:/MyProject/SeniorProject/Mushroom Pictures/train/Class A/IMG_9604.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('D:/MyProject/SeniorProject/Mushroom Pictures/train/Class A/IMG_9605.jpg')

img1_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
img2_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

h_bins = 18
s_bins = 32
histSize = [h_bins, s_bins]

h_ranges = [0,180]
s_ranges = [0,256]
ranges = h_ranges + s_ranges

channels = [0,1]

hist1c = cv2.calcHist([img1_hsv],channels,None,histSize,ranges,accumulate=False)
hist2c = cv2.calcHist([img2_hsv],[0],None,[180],[0,180],accumulate=False)
pyplot.imshow(hist1c,interpolation = 'nearest')
pyplot.show()
```

I got hs histogram as AxesImage but I want to convert to arrays for apply to machine learning model train input. Can you help me for that.
Why I didn't use hist1c and hist2c are input of the model because it's not separate H-S each diamention it only keep in the H bins.
Thank you very much :)
Big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rehsape your histogram data :

np.array(hist1c).reshape(-1, yourDataSize)